# How do I get detailed information about what happens during logon

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, windows-7, group-policy, logon-scripts

Due to my IT department leaving I am now responsible for all our IT systems. I now have several problems to get my head around and fix.

I run Active Directory on windows server 2003 and use group policy to apply settings etc. Recently we have had some windows 7 clients added to our network, these are having awful problems with our logon scripts and drive mappings. For the most part my XP clients are working without a problem.

What I want to know is what is going on during logon, as running the logon scripts after I have logged on often works. Does anyone know of a way to get detailed log information of what is happening before and during logon.

Thanks for your help and any suggestions you have for tracking down the source of these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is enable [userenv logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221833) (User Environment).  Keep in mind that these logs will be extremely verbose.

Then follow these excellent articles for what is happening during the creation of the user environment.

- [Part 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/11/11/understanding-how-to-read-a-userenv-log-part-1.aspx)
- [Part 2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/11/11/understanding-how-to-read-a-userenv-log-part-2.aspx)

Comment: Do you know how to enable this for Windows 7

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Didn't catch Windows 7.  Apparently there are changes to this procedure in this edition.  Have a look here:  http://techibee.com/group-policies/enable-group-policy-debugging-on-windows-7/191

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you write separate logon scripts that you know work on windows 7, and group the machines in different OUs.